# How to get the image or movie path from the photo Library in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code and I'm having a problem trying to get the image path :(
I searched in google and stack over flow but the solution that I found were in objective-c or code that doesn't work anymore in swift :(
so this is my code :

```
@IBAction func chooseWaterMark(sender: AnyObject) {
    var photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    photoPicker.delegate = self
    photoPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    waterMark.image = image
    waterMarkAlpha.image = image
    waterMarkAlpha.alpha = CGFloat(0.5)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend whenever possible show suitable code (including code that does exactly what you want in another language) and vote up answers to encourage others to respond to your questions. Just wanted to drop a note that almost all objc solutions can be re-typed as Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may help you:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
    let imageName = imageURL.path!.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String
    let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    data.writeToFile(localPath, atomically: true)

    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
    let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
    let imageWithData = UIImage(data: imageData)!

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

With this code you can save image to the given directory. Hope it will help.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is nil

Comment: I have stored images into an array how can I use this method?

Comment: Can you please look at my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45842393/755621 
I am not sure how it will work with my situation. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am getting a problem in the third line : `let imageName = imageURL.path!.lastPathComponent`. I think lastPathComponent is deprecated.If this issue gets resolved, complete function will work. Need help