# how to get UrlPath and name of images in the array in swift 3?

Tags: image, url, swift3, path, nsfilemanager

I have an array of images that selected from gallery in the swift 3 
I used method below for get these images url path and names but It doesn't work for me 
I read  this 
[How to get the image or movie path from the photo Library in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368867/how-to-get-the-image-or-movie-path-from-the-photo-library-in-swift#answer-31368995)
 but the problem is that I stored images in the array and want to get url path and names from this array

here is the codes

```
let imageURL = init[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
            let imageName = imageURL.path!.lastPathComponent
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
            let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            data.writeToFile(localPath, atomically: true)

            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
            let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
            let imageWithData = UIImage(data: imageData)!
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3** try this code.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
let imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
    do {
        try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
        print("file saved")
    }catch {
        print("error saving file")
    }
}
else {
    print("file already exists")
}
```

}

Comment: I don't want to use this function because I already get the images into an array