# Image-picker display multiple images like collage without memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, image, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using this [ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker/) to select multiple images from library or camera. Once user is done selecting images, I am storing those images in to an array. I want display images to the Frame according to number of images selected. for example, if more than 5 images selected the result will be something like this from the selected Images.
[image]

Imagepicker is new for me. I don't know how to achieve this. I've read many posts but not getting clear idea how to implement in my case.

I am testing it on [Demo](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker/tree/master/Demo/ImagePickerDemo) project given,

```
func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {

    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    imageArray = images
    createCollage()
}

func createCollage() {

}
```

If I use UIimageView to display/load images it shows massive memory usage.

Can please anyone help me here with any of these issue? Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: It sounds more like you need to learn how to do a custom UICollectionView. [Custom UICollectionView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: Thank you for the response @MwcsMac. I tried with the collection view too but the memory issue is still there if selecting more than 4/5 images.

Comment: Plus, if user selects only 1 image than it should cover the whole space with only one image. Is it possible with collectionView then ?

Comment: Is your image array the locations of the images? Or is it the images them selves (Which will cause memory usage)? CollectionView is like a tableView for images.

Comment: You are right. Its images them selves. How do I find the location URL for the images ?

Comment: I take it that you are not saving the images into your apps directory structure or into core data.  You should start with that by looking at this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368867/how-to-get-the-image-or-movie-path-from-the-photo-library-in-swift)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152685/discussion-between-mwcsmac-and-snehal).

Comment: Sorry for delayed response @MwcsMac. would you be able to participate in the chat at the moment ?

Answer (score 0):

look at the doc and code of ImagePicker, they are recommend to use

```
public var imageAssets: [UIImage] {
    return AssetManager.resolveAssets(imagePicker.stack.assets)
}
```

by looking for `AssetManager.resolveAssets` implementation we will se some config size

```
open static func resolveAsset(_ asset: PHAsset, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280), completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> Void) {
```

set **size** depends from your **imageView size**

--- UPD

or use the property

```
open var preferredImageSize: CGSize?
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I tried with changing size to 420 but still taking too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the same code on real device and it is working fine. In my case, testing on simulator was causing massive memory usage issue here.